# c++ (non-built in/class) static member

Tags: c++, class, static, member

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class c1
{
 public:
  static std::string m1;
  static unsigned int m2;
};

//std::string c1::m1 = std::string;
unsigned int c1::m2 = 0;

void main()
{
 c1 a;
 //std::cout<<a.m1<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<a.m2<<std::endl;
}
```

In this program enabling the two remarked lines causes an error on the first.

error C2275: 'std::string' : illegal use of this type as an expression

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all, you are using the *type* `std::string` as the *value* to be assigned.

To fix this you can do:

```
std::string c1::m1 = std::string();
                                ^^
```

or just

```
std::string c1::m1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Because "std::string" is a type, not a value.  Here is an example that might make this more obvious:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class c1
{
public:
  static unsigned int m2;
};

unsigned int c1::m2 = int; // error: int is a type, not a value

void main()
{
  c1 a;
  std::cout<<a.m2<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string c1::m1 = std::string;
```

should be something like

```
std::string c1::m1 = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the right-hand use of `std::string` on that line - you're trying to initialise the *value* of m1 to the *type* `std::string`.

You should find that a line like `std::string c1::m1 = "Wee - a string!";` will work.